# Angular - Avoid scientific notation for [(ngModel)] number input field

Tags: javascript, angular, input, number-formatting

In an application, I use an edit field to display and modify satoshi (example: `0.00000004`).

This field is linked to the data model with a `[(ngModel)]`.
the data type is a number.

Angular (or rather javascript or html) systematically translates it on loading in scientific notation: (example: `4e-8`)

The type of field used "`text`" or "`number`" produces the same effect.

Is there a fancy way to force unscientific notation **with a field bound to the data model and without changing the data model** ?

Simple javascript example of the issue :

```js
const elText = document.getElementById("satoshiText");
const elNumber = document.getElementById("satoshiNumber");
elText.value =0.00000001;
elNumber.value =0.00000001;
```

```html
<input id="satoshiText" type="text" /><br /><br />
<input id="satoshiNumber" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the value and event binding separately rather than using a two-way binding, you can add a pipe to format the number:

```
<input [ngModel]="value | number:'1.8-8'" (ngModelChange)="value = $event">
```

If you need this often, you could also write a custom form component whose `ControlValueAccessor` converts to the desired format.

Comment: nearly perfect. A small adaptation, I changed it to 'number:1.0-8'